# How to see why a process call failed

Tags: 14.04, process

From python i make several `subprocess.Popen` calls, and some of them are failing? How do I see what's happened to them and if they're still around or if there are orphan processes lying about? ps aux didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

If it is an "internal" python error, you should be able to see the error anyway by running your code in the terminal or in Idle. If it is an error in the command, you can find out by replacing your command as in the below example:

```py
test = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", "monkey"], stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
print(test.stderr.read().decode("utf-8"))
```

outputs:

```
/bin/bash: monkey: command not found
```

Comment: thanks, the error is comming from a library, the process is being opened in line 70 [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/py/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/service.py)